# Функция swap() для изменения элементов массива структур

Tags: c

Есть массив структур. Написал функцию свапа

```
swap(Struc *x1, Struc *x2)
{
  Struc *temp;
  temp = x1;
  x1 = x2;
  x2 = temp;
}
```

Пытаюсь вызвать ее `swap(&mass[i], &mass[i+1])` но столкнулся с проблемой, что реально в массиве ничего не меняется местами. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: присваивайте значения, а не адреса

Comment: не могли бы пример кода написать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы меняете местами сами указатели, но не значения. Попробуйте так:

```
swap(Struc *x1, Struc *x2)
{
  Struc temp;
  temp = *x1;
  *x1 = *x2;
  *x2 = temp;
}
```